# How to change a character's current place in javascript? #javascript

Tags: javascript

An example, I have a string 'Hi my name is junayed, and I love learning, especially programming.'
I want to check if it contains 'a', 'y' and 'm'.

if the string contains 'a' it should change it's place one point further such as 'name' will become 'nmae', more examples =>

junayed => if there's a 'y' after 'a' than it will convert to 'junyead'....
programming => if there's a 'm' after 'a' it will convert to 'progmraming'. (m moves two-point to left)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you have written so far while attempting to solve this?

Comment: as others have pointed out, the current question is unanswerable without some example code.

Comment: Your logic for "name" fails: it has an "m" after an "a" - what should the code do: move the "a" one to the right (1st condition) = "nmae", or move the "m" two to the left (3rd condition) = "mnae"?

Comment: actually I didn't started coding. I want to make an ANSI to Unicode converter (language Bengali, which is pretty complex).

I will have to face those problems which I mentioned above. Since I'm new, so thought, maybe I should ask the pros.

Comment: let fullInteger = '';
const sentenceText = 'junayed';
for (let i = 0; i < sentenceText.length; i++) {
    if (sentenceText[i] == 'n' & sentenceText[i + 1] == 'a') {
        let newChar = sentenceText[i]
        newChar = 'a';
        fullInteger = fullInteger + newChar;
      
    }
    else if (sentenceText[i] == 'a' & sentenceText[i - 1] == 'n') {
        let newChar = sentenceText[i]
        newChar = 'n';
        fullInteger = fullInteger + newChar;
        
    }
    else{
        fullInteger = fullInteger + sentenceText[i];
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the string to array of chars and then map onto it, with custom annex function(s) like found(char)

Answer (score 1):

write a placechange function that would:

1. convert the string to an array of characters
2. loop through the characters
3. condition where loop value equals search value (your 'a' or 'y' or 'm' in this case)
4. implement switch function if condition is met.